# Is it better to create Navigation Tab using FragmentTabHost or SlidingTabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

Tutorial found in [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) can't be used together with Toolbar and Android 5.0. The alternative solution is to use [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout). But currently, I found [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).

Which method is better? What is the pros and cons for each of them? What method should I use? I've googled it and found nothing regarding the comparison between them.

Answer (score 0):

Having same question. After looking at it, it's depending on your requirement.
If it does not need sliding the FragmentTabHost is enough.